# How ot uncheck Bootstrap check box

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am trying to check and uncheck the bootstrap checkbox. I am using a var test. which value I am getting from DB.
If the value is zero(0) I want to uncheck the checkbox, and if the value is one(1) I want to check the checkbox. it looks pretty simple.

**Jquery**

```
if (test == 0) {
  $('#myCheck').prop('checked', false);
  alert("I am false");
} else {
  $('#myCheck').prop('checked', true);
  alert("I am True");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <label class="control-label" for="pwd">My checkbox:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked id="myCheck" />
        <button type="button" class="btn-chk" data-color="success" ></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the `test` is zero(0), it comes into the `if block` and I get the alert message `I am false` and when it's true I come into `else block` I get the message  `I am true` but, Checkbox is always checked. Where I am making mistake?. I would appreciate any help.

Update 1:

Bellow is the code what I am using for customising the checkbox button

```js
$(function () {
    $('.button-checkbox').each(function () {

        // Settings
        var $widget = $(this),
            $button = $widget.find('button'),
            $checkbox = $widget.find('input:checkbox'),
            color = $button.data('color'),
            settings = {
                on: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check'
                },
                off: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked'
                }
            };

        // Event Handlers
        $button.on('click', function () {
            $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
            $checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
            updateDisplay();
        });
        $checkbox.on('change', function () {
            updateDisplay();
        });

        // Actions
        function updateDisplay() {
            var isChecked = $checkbox.is(':checked');

            // Set the button's state
            $button.data('state', (isChecked) ? "on" : "off");

            // Set the button's icon
            $button.find('.state-icon')
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon);

            // Update the button's color
            if (isChecked) {
                $button
                    .removeClass('btn-default-chk')
                    .addClass('btn-' + color + ' active');
            }
            else {
                $button
                    .removeClass('btn-' + color + ' active')
                    .addClass('btn-default-chk');
            }
        }

        // Initialization
        function init() {

            updateDisplay();

            // Inject the icon if applicable
            if ($button.find('.state-icon').length == 0) {
                $button.prepend('<i class="state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon + '"></i> ');
            }
        }
        init();
    });
});
```

is above code is causing the issue. could anyone please let me know

Comment: I just used your code and its working fine for me.. see here https://jsfiddle.net/zsgh9umn/

Comment: are you wrapping your js in `ready`? this could be down to the js running before the dom has loaded.

Comment: The way you have used is correct and its even working here for me. Can you check if anything external is causing this behavior for you?

Comment: @BG101 No I am not wrapping my js in ready. I have created a function which called on load. That method finds out the value of test from db

Comment: @Nikhil Nanjappa Please check updated question

Comment: @Leothelion  I have updated the question can you please check

Comment: This too is working fine. Check my Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jetgqhn6/) please. Let me know what you want from here.

Comment: Also can you mention which version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Jquery version `jquery-1.11.2`

Comment: I used the same version as you and my Fiddle still works. Can you have a look and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var eu_want_team = $('#eu_want_team').is(':checked');
alert(eu_want_team);
```

or

```
if($("#eu_want_team").prop("checked"))
{


}
```

Comment: remove checked from <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked id="myCheck" />